# Почему так происходит в MySql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Я скачал с репозитория удаленной разработки проект, проект работает на базе MySql. Беру и накатываю дамп базы и в результате получаю ошибку типа `ERROR 1101 (42000) at line 5034: BLOB, TEXT, GEOMETRY or JSON column 'comment' can't have a default value`
Настройки моего сервера и сервера коллеги одинаковые все по дефолту. У коллеги этой ошибки нет при разворачивании дампа,а у меня есть. Как разгадать почему так происходит. У меня и у него Win 10 MySQL Workbench

Comment: Чудес не бывает. Разное поведение == разные настройки. Что Вы не нашли разницы, не показатель. А "все настройки по дефолту" - вообще фэйк.

Comment: На самом деле все указанные типы не могут иметь дефолтное значение чуть ли не от сотворения мира... и это не фиксится никакими настройками. Так что просто отыщите в дампе ту инструкцию, которая приводит к ошибке, и посмотрите на неё попристальнее. А ещё лучше - сверьте версии MySQL-cерверов, и сравните их с информацией из комментария условного выполнения проблемной инструкции.